# Using PATH_INFO and creating links

Tags: php

I am using PATH_INFO to serve a page (front controller), however making links is a slight issue, as the URL is rather appending to the current URL than redirecting directly, So I end up having something like this in the URL:

```
http://localhost/routing/index.php/user/index.php/user/index.php/user/index.php

echo '<a href="index.php">Home</a> ';
echo '<a href="index.php/user/123">User 123</a>';
```

How should I solve this, an absolute url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML to use absolute path you have to add slash in front of your path.

Eg. `/index.php`.

Comment: That will move me back to the root if it's in a sub directory

Comment: @John If you want to stay in directory you can use links like before but with `?` after file extension. You can also use mod_rewrite to hide `index.php`.